# Form Submissions via API

Tags: api, hubspot

I have a form embedded on my website via Hubspot API. I want to receive an email notification if someone submits the form. I tried the solution given on the HubSpot community but it does seem to work. 
Here it is https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form
https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form_v3

Can anybody provide a solution? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Under Marketing -> Lead Capture -> Forms, find and open the relevant form. Click the **Options** tab at the top and in the middle of the page locate **Send submission email notifications**. Select your user from the drop down list or manually enter an email.
[image: send submission email notifications box]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that already. The form is not created using Hubspot forms, rather the submission is using an API. Hence not working.

Comment: @DebolinaBakshi do the form submissions sent through the API show up in the user interface when you open the form, go to the **Actions** dropdown and select **View Submissions**? If there are no submissions, there is something wrong with how you are sending to the API.

Comment: Checked, have submissions. Still not getting notifications

Comment: Do normal submissions through that form create a notification?

Comment: The leads are getting submitted but I am not getting any notifications in my mail